# How to type modules that aren't NPM packages with Flow?

Tags: flowtype

**Disclaimer**: *I'm new to Flow and very confused by its documentation so I might be missing something obvious here.*

I have a module as follows:

```
// ./src/lib/myModule/MyModule.js
// @flow
class MyModule {
  constructor(str) {
    this.aString = str
  }
}
export { MyModule as AnotherName }
```

I export the module this way so I can import `./myModule` and still split `MyModule` across several files if I need to:

```
// ./src/lib/myModule/index.js
export * from './MyModule'
```

I also have a types file:

```
// ./src/lib/myModule/MyModule.types.js
// @flow
declare module 'MyModule' {
  declare class MyModule {
    sString: string;
    constructor(str: string);
  }
}
```

I then use the module:

```
// ./src/index.js
// @flow
import { MyModule } from './src/lib/myModule';

const myModule = new MyModule('foo')
```

This is the whole directory layout:

```
src/
├── index.js
└── lib
    └── myModule
        ├── index.js
        ├── MyModule.js
        └── MyModule.types.js
```

And this is my `.flowconfig`

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/build/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/coverage/*

[include]

[libs]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/**/*.types.js

[lints]
sketchy-null=error
untyped-type-import=warn
untyped-import=warn
unclear-type=error
unsafe-getters-setters=warn

[options]
suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIgnore

[strict]

[version]
^0.69.0
```

How do I get Flow to understand that the declaration in `src/lib/myModule/MyModule.types.js` pertains to `src/lib/myModule/MyModule.js`? I can't find a syntax to tell flow that the class MyModule is the same in the ES Module file and the types file.

Answer (score -1):

MyModule.types.js needs to be named MyModule.js.flow. When you import a file, flow will automatically pull type information from a .js.flow file with the same name, if it exists. You are correct that this information is currently missing from the flow docs: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3609

The contents of MyModules.js.flow should be

```
// @flow

declare export class AnotherName {
  sString: string;
  constructor(str: string): AnotherName;
}
```

Couple of changes from what you had:

- You do not need to declare a module here. Flow understands that the .js.flow file only pertains to this file, so we are not declaring a global.
- Need to declare the return type of constructor (AnotherName).
- Declare the export as AnotherName rather than MyModule, since the files importing this class see AnotherName; the name used inside the module itself is not relevant for type checking usage of the file.

Now, when using this file,

```
// @flow

import { AnotherName } from './MyModule';

// Good
const anotherName1 = new AnotherName('123');
// Flow Error
const anotherName2 = new AnotherName(123);
```

Note that if you're re-exporting out `AnotherName` out of index.js, and always importing `AnotherName` from index.js when using it, you would need to have an index.js.flow file as well to get any benefits of type checking. Or you could add the // @flow pragma at the top of index.js.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it. The Flow error I am getting is in `MyModule.js` about it not being typed. I don't know how to express to Flow that the types for `MyModule.js` are in `MyModule.types.js`

Comment: You can't tell flow that the types are in MyMoudle.types.js. The file has to have the same name, be in the same directory, and have the .js.flow extension. MyModule.js.flow needs to be sitting right next to MyMoudle.js.

Comment: That's waht I did after your comment, but it still wasn't picking the types up. I had MyModule.js.flow sitting right next to MyModule.js and Flow still complained that things weren't typed. Not sure what I'm missing, I tried `declare module 'MyModule' {` and `declare module './src/lib/MyModule' {` or `declare module './' {`

Comment: Added some details to my original answer; it is working for me with the above setup.

Comment: Two things about this answer I don't like.  It's coming from an open issue reported on the .flow style of  declarations.  The declaration style shouldn't force a user to declare the export as AnotherName rather than MyModule. I also tried unsuccessfully to get this declaration style to work.